# What does "prod home" mean in football (soccer)?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "prod home" mean in football (soccer)?

> GOAL! LIVERPOOL 1-0 BOURNEMOUTH (MANE)
>   Andddddd we have liftoff at Anfield! Sadio Mane **prods home** at the second time of asking inside the box for his 17th goal of the season in all competitions.
>
> Asmir Begovic did so well to get down low and save Mane’s initial free header inside the penalty area, however Bournemouth’s sleeping defence did not have the awareness to get to the ball first and clear it away.
>
> The Liverpool forward picked out a free corner in the net and swept the ball flying into the back of the net. 1-0 after just seven minutes.

Comment: Please look up the word prod

Comment: I still think it's hard to understand, even if you know the meaning of the word prod.

Comment: I actually think this is pretty easy to understand even if you have no idea about "prod". It means "someone scored".  Look up prod and you get the idea about how he scored. If whitekrystal has looked up prod then he can say this.  However this question is incomplete.

Comment: I don't think it means scored. Home means into the goal or score. Prod does not. So the combination is pretty hard to understand for a non-native.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another use of it that is clearer and spells it out:

**The hosts made the perfect start when Sadio Mane followed up his own header to prod the ball past Cherries keeper Asmir Begovic**.

[prod [a ball]](http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/43678369)

to prod means to push something, it is usually used for people: He prodded me as we walking into the room. He pushed me along.

Here, prod means to "nudge the ball" to get somewhere. prod home is to nudge the ball to go into the goal.

So, in your text, the ball was being played inside the box, and apparently he got control of it a second time and he prodded it into the goal.

**If you prod a ball, you are not kicking it really hard**. You are nudging it or pushing it along, **probably without the ball even coming off the ground**.

Answer (score 0):

Prod is as appropriate to use about objects as it is about people - one can prod a push-button, e.g. of an electric doorbell, or something that is stuck. The verb means "to poke with a finger, foot, or pointed object". She prodded the cake with her fork to see if it was cooked. You can prod wood to see if it is rotten.